# Char array and pointer char array

Tags: c

I have some problem for this output. Also, I also want some examples on how to use `char *str`.

```
int main() {
    char str[5];
    scanf_s("%c", &str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The output came out weird for the input *"VI"*.

Comment: `scanf_s` takes a pointer as an input, just like `printf`. You don't need to do `&`

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Comment: You don't terminate the string.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"some problem for this output"* and *"The output came out weird"*?  (Respond by editing your question, not here in comments (as appropriate)).

Comment: https://imgur.com/yRB0I0r this is the output i got. even if I changed to scanf_s("%c",str)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf_s` takes pointer as its argument. So you don't need to use `&str`, because `str` is implicitly converted to a pointer when used in expressions like an argument expression. You can also pass the buffer size as a parameter in `scanf_s`.

So you can use

```
scanf_s("%c", str, 5);
```

where 5 is the buffer size. Passing a specific buffer size will restrict you taking input more than the size which is missing `scanf`. In `scanf` you may take more input than the array or string size (like declared string is `char str[4]`, but you may take input `'Hello'`) which later causes crashing the program due to overflow. But using particular buffer size in scanf_f  will not allow you taking more input than the buffer size. This is where the scanf_s comes in.

Comment: imgur.com/yRB0I0r this is the output i got. even if I changed to scanf_s("%c",str)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need a pointer as an argument to `scanf_s`, which is exactly what `str` decays to when passed to a function, so you don't need the `&` operator, and also you need to specify a buffer size:

```
scanf_s("%c", str, 5);
```

You can find the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).

Comment: See also *[How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318)*, *[What does getting the address of an array variable mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202077)*, and *[Address of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694)*.