# C program: Changing the string in a function by using double pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void fun(char** a)
{
    strcpy(*a, "ponky" );
}

int main()
{
    char a[100] = "pinky";
    fun(&a );
    printf("\n %s \n", a );
    return 0;
}
```

Copying a string in a function through double pointer.
Why the above program gives segmentation fault?

Comment: *"warning: incompatible pointer types passing `char (*)[100]` to parameter of type `char **`"* If you didn't see that warning, you need to enable more warnings, e.g. by using `-Wall` with gcc or clang. If you **did** see that warning, but ignored it, then the lesson for the day is: don't ignore warnings.

Comment: The correct declaration is `void fun(char *a)` and then `strcpy(a, "pony");` and call the function with `fun(a);`

Comment: `fun(&a );` is not a `char **` but `char *` more precisely `char (*)[100]`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before but I can't find an exact duplicate right now. Anyway - this should tell you everything :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: Also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202077/what-does-getting-the-address-of-an-array-variable-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*note: I suspect this question to be a duplicate and I've found many similar questions but I haven't found an exact duplicate. Therefore I post an answer. Should someone find an exact duplicate I'll remove this answer.*

> Why the above program gives segmentation fault?

The short answer is that you have a type mismatch when calling `fun`. You don't give `fun` a "pointer to pointer to char" as it expects. Consequently, it fails big time.

**But what do you then pass to `fun`?** **And how should you have found out that something was wrong?**

The answer is: **Set compiler warning level high and consider all warnings to be errors**

For `gcc` that could be:

```
gcc -xc -Wall -pedantic -Werror main.c
```

(Other compilers have similar options)

On my system I get:

```
In function 'main':
error: passing argument 1 of 'fun' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   13 | fun(&a );
      |     ^~
      |     |
      |     char (*)[100]
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'
    3 | void fun(char** a)
      |          ~~~~~~~^
```

so it's clear that something is wrong and the following line tells it all:

```
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[100]'
```

you pass `char (*)[100]` instead of `char **`

**But what is `char (*)[100]`?**

It's a "pointer to an array of char". Since `fun` uses it as "pointer to pointer to char" you have undefined behavior (which in your case resulted in a seg fault). That is - `fun` would expect `*a` to be a "pointer to char" but you passed "pointer to an array of char" so `*a` is not a "pointer to char".

It's undefined behavior so we can't tell what is going on. However, on many systems it will read the string "pinky" and interpretate it as a pointer to char which will fail big time.