# How are 2-Dimensional Arrays stored in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[101][101];
    a[2][0]=10;
    cout<<a+2<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+2)<<endl;
    cout<<*(*(a+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Why are the values of `a+2` and `*(a+2)` same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could just be coincidence, if you believe in that sort of thing...

Comment: Even if pointer value printed are the same, type are not.

Comment: You're in luck! Today, and only today, on stackoverflow.com we have a special going: answer your own question! Create a small array, say `int a[2][2]`. Put four values into it, say 1, 2, 3, and 4. Get a pointer to the first element, `int *p=&a[0][0];`. Then look, with a debugger, what `p` is pointing to, and answer your own question. What a bargain!!

Comment: [Pieces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice) of [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Take a look at [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456), it shows how an array of arrays is laid out in memory.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: it is not by coincidence, but surprisingly it is required by standard... I had to read the code twice to make sure that no UB was involved, but it is perfectly correct code.

Comment: c.f. effective duplicate from today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202077/what-does-getting-address-of-array-variable-mean/38203803 and the one _it_'s a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552960/about-the-expression-anarray-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a` is a 2D array, that means an array of arrays. But it *decays* to a pointer to an array when used in appropriate context. So:

- in `a+2`, `a` decays to a pointer to int arrays of size 101. When you pass is to an ostream,  you get the address of the first element of this array, that is `&(a[2][0])`
- in `*(a+2)` is *by definition* `a[2]`: it is an array of size 101 that starts at `a[2][0]`. It decays to a pointer to int, and when you pass it to an ostream you get the address of its first element, that is still `&(a[2][0])`
- `**(a+2)` is *by definition* `a[2][0]`. When you pass it to an ostream you get its int value, here 10.

But beware: `a + 2` and `a[2]` are both pointers to the same address (`static_cast<void *>(a+2)` is the same as `static_cast<void *>(a[2])`), but they are pointers to different types: first points to int array of size 101, latter to int.

Comment: Thanks! It was quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain you how the memory is mapped by the compiler:

Let's consider a more pratical example multi-dimentional array:

```
int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

You can execute the command

```
x/10w a
```

In GDB and look at the memory:

```
0x7fffffffe750: 1   2   3   4
0x7fffffffe760: 5   6   7   8
0x7fffffffe770: 9   0
```

Each element is stored in a *int* type (*32 bit / 4 bytes*).
So the first element of the matrix has been stored in:

```
1) a[0][0] -> 0x7fffffffe750
2) a[0][1] -> 0x7fffffffe754
3) a[0][2] -> 0x7fffffffe758
4) a[1][0] -> 0x7fffffffe75c
5) a[1][1] -> 0x7fffffffe760
6) a[1][2] -> 0x7fffffffe764
7) a[2][0] -> 0x7fffffffe768
        ...
```

The command:

```
std::cout << a + 2 << '\n'
```

It will print the address **0x7fffffffe768** because of the 
pointer aritmetic:
Type of **a** is **int**** so it's a pointer to pointers.
a+2 is the a[0] (the first row) + 2. The result is a pointer
to the third row.

*(a+2) deferences the third row, that's {7,8,9}

The third row is an array of int, that's a pointer to int.

Then the operator<< will print the value of that pointer.

Comment: In this example, isn't the type of `a` actually `int[3][3]`?

Comment: @flatmouse you're right. It's more accurate to say the type is int[3][3] that's because the size is static, compile time.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional array is an array of arrays, so it's stored like this in memory:

```
char v[2][3] = {{1,3,5},{5,10,2}};

Content: | 1 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 2
Address:   v  v+1 v+2 v+3 v+4 v+5
```

To access v[x][y], the compiler rewrites it as: `*(v + y * M + x)` (where M is the second dimension specified)

For example, to access v[1][1], the compiler rewrites it as `*(v + 1*3 + 1)` => `*(v + 4)`

Be aware that this is **not** the same as a pointer to a pointer (char**).
A pointer to a pointer is not an array: it contains and address to a memory cell, which contains another address.

To access a member of a 2-dimensional array using a pointer to a pointer, this is what is done:

```
char **p;
/* Initialize it */
char c = p[3][5];
```

1. Go to the address specified by the content of `p`;
2. Add the offset to that address (3 in our case);
3. Go to that address and get its content (our new address).
4. Add the second offset to that new address (5 in our case).
5. Get the content of that address.

While to access the member via a traditional 2-dimensional array, these are the steps:

```
char p[10][10];
char c = p[3][5];
```

1. Get the address of `p`and sum the first offset (3), multiplied by the dimension of a row (10).
2. Add the the second offset (5) to the result.
3. Get the content of that address.

Comment: What is I have not specified either rows or columns statically. What happens to this formula `*(v + y * M + x)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array like this

```
T a[N];
```

then the name of the array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element with rare exceptions (as for example using an array name in the `sizeof` operator).

So for example in expression `( a + 2 )` `a` is converted type `T *` with value `&a[0]`.

Relative to your example wuth array

```
int a[101][101];
```

in expression

```
a + 2
```

a is converted to rvalue of type `int ( * )[101]` and points to the first "row" of the array. `a + 2` points to the third "row" of the array. The type of the row is `int[101]`

Expression `*(a+2)` gives this third row that has type `int[101]` that is an array. And this array as it is used in an expression in turn is converted to pointer to its first element of type `int *`.

It is the same starting address of the memory area occupied by the third row.

Only expression `( a + 2 )` has type `int ( * )[101]` while expression `*( a + 2 )` has type `int *`. But the both yield the same value - starting address of the memory area occupied by the third row of the array `a`.

Comment: Thanks! It was quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of an array is at the same location as the array itself - there is no "empty space" in an array.

In `cout << a + 2`, `a` is implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element, `&a[0]`, and `a + 2` is the location of `a`'s third element, `&a[2]`.

In `cout << *(a + 2)`, the array `*(a + 2)` - that is, `a[2]` - is converted into a pointer to its first element, `&a[2][0]`.

Since the location of the third element of `a` and the location of the first element of the third element of `a` are the same, the output is the same.