# Swap rows in a 2D array with std::swap. How does it work?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I'm mostly just documenting this question as someone may stumble upon it, and may find it useful. And also, I'm very curios with, how does `std::swap` works on a 2D array like: `Arr[10][10]`.
My question arised because as to my understanding an array like this is just a 1D array with some reindexing.
For reference:
[How are 2-Dimensional Arrays stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204677/how-are-2-dimensional-arrays-stored-in-memory)

```cpp
int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    const int y = 10;
    int Arr[y][x];
    // fill the array with some elements...
    for (int i = 0; i < x*y; i++)
    {
        Arr[i / y][i % x] = i;
    }

    // swap 'row 5 & 2'
    // ??? how does swap know how many elements to swap?
    // if it is in fact stored in a 1D array, just the
    // compiler will reindex it for us
    std::swap(Arr[5], Arr[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I could understand swapping two 'rows' if our data type is, say a pointer to a pointer like `int** Arr2D` then swap with `std::swap(Arr2D[2], Arr2D[5])` as we do not need to know the length here, we just need to swap the two pointers, pointing to '1D arrays'.
But how does `std::swap` work with `Arr[y][x]`?

Is it using a loop maybe, to swap all elements within `x` length?

Comment: The short answer is `type` is king. A 2D array decays to a pointer to the first 1D array on access. (in your case a *pointer-to-array of int [10]*) `std::swap` is required to know the size of what it must swap and by dereferencing the pointer-to-array by using `[...]` leaves the type as `int[10]` which `std::swap` can deal with. You are swapping two `int[10]` arrays.

Comment: For the basis in the standards (both applicable), see [C Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) incorporated for fundamental types and extended in [C++ Standard - 7.3.2 Array-to-pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::swap` has an overload for arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) that effectively swaps each two elements, again, using `std::swap`.

As for the size information, it is embedded within the array type (`Arr[i]` is `int[x]`), so the compiler knows to *deduce* `T2` as `int` and `N` as `10`.

OT: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) ([but this particular case is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996258/array-initialization-use-const-variable-in-c))